# Combine rows on case when with non numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, case-when

HI all i'm trying to get all rows rolled up to one. I have tried MAX Case when but there is a non numeric string in the case when and it isn't working to roll up the data. I have tried to find other examples but can't so i'm asking for your help. Thanks in advance

I have two fields that have different data but all have the same control number and i need to get all data for the control number rolled into one row.

```
SELECT CNTL_NUM
  ,TRANS_TYP
  ,CASE WHEN SEQ_NUM = '02' THEN SUBSTRING(TRANS_INFO,28,9) END AS 'SSN' 
  ,CASE WHEN SEQ_NUM = '11' THEN SUBSTRING(TRANS_INFO,46,2) END AS 'IPS_STATE'
  FROM LVJPROD.IPS_LNA
  WHERE TRANS_TYP = 'TA'
  GROUP BY CNTL_NUM, TRANS_TYP,SEQ_NUM,TRANS_INFO
  order by CNTL_NUM
```

I am hoping to get all 6 lines rolled up to one from the screen shot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can group them again. The problem is with the case statement where it manipulates data. So you need to treat these as a subquery and have a grouping in the outer query and the `MAX` should work

```
WITH yourtable 
 AS (SELECT cntl_num, 
            trans_typ, 
            CASE 
              WHEN seq_num = '02' THEN Substring(trans_info, 28, 9) 
            END AS ssn, 
            CASE 
              WHEN seq_num = '11' THEN Substring(trans_info, 46, 2) 
            END AS ips_state 
     FROM   lvjprod.ips_lna 
     WHERE  trans_typ = 'TA' 
     GROUP  BY cntl_num, 
               trans_typ, 
               seq_num, 
               trans_info) 
SELECT cntl_num, 
       trans_typ, 
       Max(ssn), 
       Max(ips_state) 
FROM   yourtable 
GROUP  BY cntl_num, 
          trans_typ 
ORDER  BY cntl_num;
```

OR

```
SELECT cntl_num, 
       trans_typ, 
       Max(ssn), 
       Max(ips_state) 
FROM   (SELECT cntl_num, 
               trans_typ, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN seq_num = '02' THEN Substring(trans_info, 28, 9) 
               END AS ssn, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN seq_num = '11' THEN Substring(trans_info, 46, 2) 
               END AS ips_state 
        FROM   lvjprod.ips_lna 
        WHERE  trans_typ = 'TA' 
        GROUP  BY cntl_num, 
                  trans_typ, 
                  seq_num, 
                  trans_info) a 
GROUP  BY cntl_num, 
          trans_typ 
ORDER  BY cntl_num;
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept/upvote this answer to denote this is useful.